# Initialize StatefulWidget state null safe from widget constructor in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, initialization, dart-null-safety

I want to have a `StatefulWidget` where I can pass the initial value for a non-nullable member of the widgets `State` from the widgets constructor.

My current solution (see below) seems to be not ideal, I see two problems with it:

1. The initial value has to be saved in the widget itself before passing it to the state.
2. The member in the sate has to be marked as `late` since it can only be set after initialization.

Is there a better way to initialize a `StatefulWidget`'s state non-nullable member from a value passed to the widget constructor?

---

My current implementation:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  const MyWidget({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  late String text;

  @override
  void initState() {
    text = widget.text;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(text);
  }
}
```

(Not shown here, but later the `text` member should be changeable, that's why it is in the `State`)

Comment: To elaborate on why I want to avoid the two mentioned problems: 1) seems wasteful 2) compile time null-safety checks are preferred to runtime checks imo.

Answer (score 1):

hey there your code seems good.
but the better way is using bloc to pass and receive data.
any way . its not necessary to pass and fill data in initstate and _MyWidgetState .
you can receive your data directly in build widget As you wrote (widget.text)
here is some good things for avoid nullable
https://codewithandrea.com/videos/dart-null-safety-ultimate-guide-non-nullable-types/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the constructor of State like this: `_MyWidgetState(){ text=widget.text; }`. The constructor will certainly be executed before initState and build methods.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Initializing the variable in the constructor body is to late (`Non-nullable instance field 'text' must be initialized. Try adding an initializer expression.`), but doing it in the initializer as `_MyWidgetState() : text=widget.text;` doesn't work either (`The instance member 'widget' can't be accessed in an initializer.`)

Comment: I found that you can take another approach like `_MyWidgetState(this.text);`. And at widget `State<MyApp> createState() => _MyWidgetState(text);` pass the variable.